# Check if values for a key in a array of hash are defined?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like so

```
[ {a:nil,...}, {a:nil,...}, ... ]
```

I'd like to check to if the value for all elements or for a particular key in the hash array are nil.

I know you do this for a single hash like so

```
hash.values.include? nil
```

Is there a better way than having to iter through the array and checking each hash?

Comment: What do you mean by "key value"? Do you mean all values of a hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
array.all?{|h| h.values.all?(&:nil?)}
```

For a particular key `key`:

```
array.all?{|h| h[key].nil?}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Is there a better way than having to iterate through the array and checking each hash?"

Yes, you can make use of the Ruby's Enumerable **[all?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F)** to avoid looping through the array and checking each hash. The following are the two examples:

```
1.9.3p286 :001 > a = [{:a=>nil, :b=>nil}, {:a=>nil, :c=>nil}, {:d=> 1, :e=>nil}]
 => [{:a=>nil, :b=>nil}, {:a=>nil, :c=>nil}, {:d=>1, :e=>nil}] 
1.9.3p286 :002 > a.all?{|h| h.values.all?(&:nil?)}
 => false 
1.9.3p286 :003 > a = [{:a=>nil, :b=>nil}, {:a=>nil, :c=>nil}]
 => [{:a=>nil, :b=>nil}, {:a=>nil, :c=>nil}] 
1.9.3p286 :004 > a.all?{|h| h.values.all?(&:nil?)}
 => true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842932/check-if-values-for-a-key-in-a-array-of-hash-are-defined).

Comment: You can say so, just tried to elaborate, explain and show what's going on there. @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1):

This also works, though I would recommend @sawa's solutions.

**Code**

```
def all_nil?(array)
  array.flat_map(&:values).compact.empty?
end

def each_all_nil?(array)
  array.map { |h| h.values.compact.empty? }
end
```

**Examples**

```
array = [{dog: nil, cat: nil, bird: nil}, {rhino: nil, dog: nil, bird: nil}]
all_nil?(array)              #=> true
each_all_nil?(array)         #=> [true, true]

array = [{dog: nil, cat: nil, bird: nil}, {rhino: nil, dog: "woof", bird: nil}]
all_nil?(array)              #=> false
each_all_nil?(array)         #=> [true, false]
```

**Explanation**

```
array = [{dog: nil, cat: nil, bird: nil}, {rhino: nil, dog: "woof", bird: nil}]
```

For `all_nil?`

```
a = array.flat_map(&:values) #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, "woof", nil]
b = a.compact                #=> ["woof"]
b.empty?                     #=> false
```

For `each_all_nil?`

When mapping the first element of `array`:

```
a = array.first              #=> {:dog=>nil, :cat=>nil, :bird=>nil}
b = a.values                 #=> [nil, nil, nil]
c = b.compact                #=> []
c.empty?                     #=> true
```